# Offset object/bone animation

Tags: animation, bones

Is possible to offset animation in Blender.

For example. I have an animation of a hand grabing a gun, but I need to change how hand grabs the gun. Is there a way, to change only first pose, so any later ones will update? 
Something like offseting mode for transforms, to add an offset to actual transforms. Am I clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use delta transform or just move up the whole graph in graph editor.

**Delta trasform:**
[image: delta transform]

**Graph editor:**
[image: move graph up]

Comment: Thank You. Delta transform aren't present in bone animation, and editing graph is tedious. Sadly it's the only way.